# Oculus/Unity - OVRCameraRig not set to instance of object in example scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, oculus

I'm using MacOS High Sierra, latest Oculus Unity framework, Oculus example scenes, and Unity 2017.4.

I am trying to understand whether this is a Mac issue or just me not having a Rift plugged in - basically I need to START developing a VR project before I have an actual Oculus Rift and PC. I will have them, but need to start on the code NOW.

I just tried to set up the example scene and got error -

[image]

Is there a way to test without a Rift plugged in? Tried VRTK and did not work with Mac? What can I do here?

Comment: Looks like an issue with not having a headset plugged in. If you have code that you have write now you can still do it, just not test it. You should look into [headset simulators](https://vrtoolkit.readme.io/docs/vr-simulator), or just work on parts of your game that don't depend on the headset.

Comment: @BenjaFriend right, I tried VRTK - have you had luck using it on a mac? I tried it but got a similar error since im on a mac high sierra